# XAttribute create p0:dt instead of dt:dt

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to create below line in my XML file by using Linq to XML

```
<custom-attribute name="displayName" dt:dt="string" xml:lang="en-US">
```

but I have been stuck in creating `dt:dt = "string"`.

Here is the code:

```
var elements = new List<XElement>();
XNamespace valueDt = XNamespace.Get("dt");
elements.Add(new XElement(elementName, new XAttribute("name", "displayName"), new XAttribute(valueDt + "dt", "string"), new XAttribute(xml + "lang", "en-US"), value.enU));
```

But in the document instead of `dt:dt = "string"`, I have `p0:dt="string"`.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: The Net library adds the p namespace when no namespace is specified.  Simply adding an empty string "" removes the p namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem. Here are my code changes

```
var elements = new List<XElement>();
XNamespace dt = XNamespace.Get("{...}/impex-dt");
elements.Add(new XElement(elementName, new XAttribute("name", "displayName"), new XAttribute(valueDt + "dt", "string"), new XAttribute(xml + "lang", "en-US"), value.enU));
```

so this means my dt value was not correct